# Comparing two unsorted collections in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to compare a large number of documents in two collections. To give you an estimate, I have around 1300 documents in each of the two collections.

I want to generate a diff comparison report after comparing the two collections. **I do not need to point out exactly what is missing or what new content has been added, I just need to be able to identify that there is in fact some difference between the two documents**. Yes, I do have a unique identifier for each documents other than Mongo's `ObjectId ("_id")`.

Note: I have implemented the database using the denormalized data model, which means I have embedded documents (documents within documents).

What would you say is the best way to go about implementing a solution for the same?

Thank you in advance for your time samaritans!

Comment: is each document (with your unique identifier) suppose to be in both collections? or is there a different way to "connect" two documents that are suppose to match?

Comment: this will help you to get towards the solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568845/mongodb-nested-array-intersection-query]

Comment: @tomslabbaert yes, both documents with the same unique identifier will be present in both the collections ,i.e., there are equal number of documents in both collections.

Comment: I dare to ask the question: *Why* have the same document in two collections? Sounds like you want them in one collection and add an additional field.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg it's not the same document. Assume that the "value" for one of the keys has changed in the second document (from the second collection). Basically, documents in the second collection might have updated values w.r.t the first collection.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the two documents and their lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and $eq on all the fields you care about.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "collection2",
           let: { unique_id: "$unique_id", field1: "$field", field2: "$field", ... },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$unique_id_in_2",  "$$unique_id" ] }
                         { $eq: [ "$field_to_match",  "$$field1" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$field_to_match.2",  "$$field2" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
           ],
           as: "matches"
         }
    },
   {
     $match: {
         'matches.0': {$exists: false}
      }
   }
])
```

** mongo 3.6+ syntax for lookup.